# Own Physics Engine: Bouncing doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I created a simple `Ball` prototype, which includes a `draw()` and a `move()` function. The ball should bounce on floor, walls and ceiling. For some reason however, it doesn't stop bouncing, although the velocity (`vy`) get's decreased continiously... Do you know what I did wrong?

```js
function Ball(radius,x,y,vx,vy,color){
 this.radius = radius;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.vx = vx;
 this.vy = vy;
 this.color = color;
 this.gravity = 0.6;
 this.friction = {
  air: 0.005,
  bounce: 0.3
 };
}

Ball.prototype.move = function(){
 this.x += this.vx;
 this.y += this.vy;
 //Gravity
 this.vy += this.gravity;
 //Air Friction
 this.vx /= 1+this.friction.air;
 this.vy /= 1+this.friction.air;
 //Bounce Border
 if(this.x<this.radius){//Left
  this.x = this.radius+((this.radius-this.x)/(1+this.friction.bounce));
  this.vx /= -(1+this.friction.bounce);
 }
 if(this.x>width-this.radius){//Right
  this.x = (width-this.radius)-((this.x-(width-this.radius))/(1+this.friction.bounce));
  this.vx /= -(1+this.friction.bounce);
 }
 if(this.y<this.radius){//Top
  this.y = this.radius+((this.radius-this.y)/(1+this.friction.bounce));
  this.vy /= -(1+this.friction.bounce);
 }
 if(this.y>height-this.radius){//Bottom
  this.y = (height-this.radius)-((this.y-(height-this.radius))/(1+this.friction.bounce));
  this.vy /= -(1+this.friction.bounce);
 }
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,2*Math.PI,false);
 ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
 ctx.fill();
};

var ctx, clock, ball
 width = 300,
 height = 150;

window.onload = function(){
 ball = new Ball(20,150,30,4,0,"red");
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 clock = setInterval(main,33);
};

function main(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
 ball.draw();
 ball.move();
}
```

```css
canvas{
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="ball.class.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div align="center">
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that when your ball would bounce, it still gets accelerated downwards for the whole tick, and because of that it bounces up further than it should.

EDIT:
Because of that, this only is a problem for the y-direction.

Comment: Sounds plausible... So how would you do that?